# Is it possible to add an install timer when you run the dd command

Tags: linux, dd

I am currently trying to make an install usb key but im not sure if the dd commmand is freezing or just taking forever and for future reference i wanted to know if it was possible to add a install timer somehow to the dd comand when copying my iso to my thumb drive

ps the iso is 4.9 gb

thank you in advanced

Comment: Try `kill -SIGUSR1 $(pidof dd)` for a start.

Comment: What is an "install timer"?  Are you looking for an estimate of how long the `dd` command will take?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to know how long its going to take or a timer of some sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pv` is a nice utility that will show a pretty progress bar for pretty much anything. To e.g. write `file.iso` to `/dev/sdd`, use

```
$ pv file.iso > /dev/sdd
3.1GB 0:02:14 [14.27MB/s] [=====================>     ] 91%
```